# How do you refer to the holidays between late December and Early January

Tags: word-choice, expressions

What is the correct way to refer to the end-of-year holiday which includes January's initial days? Like in [Australia](https://www.nsw.gov.au/living-in-nsw/public-holidays) offices are usually closed between 25 December (Christmas day) to 1 January. Yes, I know officially only one day of the new year is a public holiday but still, many people take more days after it off (like five or six days of January), so I feel "Christmas holidays" or "End of year holidays" are not accurate.

Comment: If you're only talking about some workers choosing to take a week off in January --as opposed to all school children getting a schedule two week break for Christmas and New Years-- why do you think it has a special name?

Comment: In the US we would call it vacation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally "Christmas holidays" is sufficient.

> The school will have Christmas holidays from December 17th to January 3rd. The Easter holidays start on the first of April.

If you have a pedantic and legalist mindset then "Christmas and New Year's holidays", but it doesn't really need a special "name".

Comment: In the UK, at least, more general descriptions like 'seasonal holidays' are common. For example, the University of Westminster lists 'seasonal closures', so does the British Library.  These are just the top of a Google search.

Comment: Many thanks, I prefer to refer to those holidays as "End of year holidays" and avoid "Chrismas Holidays". In that case, I'm afraid that people do not include the new year's initial days inclusive of what was intended. Do you think generally "end-or-year holidays" is sufficient like "Christmas holidays" to include the initial January too?

Comment: My answer stands.  It is normal to use "Christmas holidays" for a break from school or work at this time of year.